# Python 3.3.5 float format precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, format, precision

```
>>> '{:0.10}'.format(1/3)
'0.3333333333'
>>> '{:0.10}'.format(100/3)
'33.33333333'
```

The first gives 10 digits after the decimal point, the second gives 8. 
Does "precision" mean total digits? How do I control significant digits after the decimal point only?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the type `f` (for float) to control the number of digits after the decimal place:

```
>>> '{:.10f}'.format(100/3)
'33.3333333333'
```

Without specifying the type, Python falls back to the general number type and the number is rounded to the specified number of significant digits. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'f' and 'F', or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'g' or 'G'.

Comment: If the precision were just specifying the max size of the string, we'd be seeing one less digit. The reason we're seeing 8 digits after the decimal point is because an unspecified presentation type for `float`s treats the precision value mostly the same as `g`, where it means digits before and after the decimal point.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I referred to the wrong part of the documentation there (now fixed).

Comment: got it. Thanks for your help.